# Is there a simpler or one line method to get the selected index of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid that contains mostly DataGridViewComboBoxColumn columns as data. The number of columns in the DataGridView varies based on the type of
product being listed. To make editing of each row of the data easier I have created a modal editor to display all the columns as multiple rows and columns
(need to remove the horizontal scrolling forced on the user by the data grid). The data in one row of the datagrid needs to be transferred to the modal editor.

Obviously the controls in the modal editor will not be of type DataGridViewComboBoxCell. They are currently of type ListBox, but in most of
the cases this is easy enough to change to ComboBox.

The controls in the modal editor need to be initiated with the currently
selected values of the DataGridViewComboBox Cells if the user has previously
edited the control.

The way I originally planed to do it was to get the selected index of the
DataGridViewComboBox but that doesn't seem to exist. Is there a method to get
the selected index that does not involve comparing the Cell Value to each of
the items in the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.items list?

This question refers to the second constructor where it is looping through the list of items to get selected index.

```
public class ControlTransferData
{
    private List<string> _valueStrings;
    private string _name;
    private bool _hasSelection;
    private int _indexSelected;

    public ControlTransferData()
    {
        _valueStrings = new List<string>();
        _name = null;
        _indexSelected = -1;
        _hasSelection = false;
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
    }

    public ControlTransferData(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CboxCol, DataGridViewCell currentControlToTransfer)
    {
        _valueStrings = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in CboxCol.Items)
        {
            string itemStringValue = item.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemStringValue) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemStringValue))
            {
                _valueStrings.Add(itemStringValue);
            }
        }

        if (currentControlToTransfer.Value != null)
        {
            _hasSelection = true;
            int selectedIndex = 0;
            string selectedItem = currentControlToTransfer.Value.ToString();
            foreach (string currentString in _valueStrings)
            {
                if (currentString.CompareTo(selectedItem) == 0)
                {
                    _indexSelected = selectedIndex;
                }
                selectedIndex++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _indexSelected = -1;
            _hasSelection = false;
        }

        _name = CboxCol.HeaderText;
        Width = 0;
        Height = 0;
    }

    public string Name { set { _name = value } get { return _name; } }
    public List<string> ValueStrings { set { _valueStrings = value; } get { return _valueStrings; } }
    public bool HasSelection { set { _hasSelection = value; } get { return _hasSelection; } }
    public int IndexSelected { set { _indexSelected = value; } get { return _indexSelected; } }
    public int Width { set; get; }
    public int Height { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code:

```
 myDGV.Columns["SampleColumn"].Index;
```

This would work in winForms.

Comment: @pacmaninbw : Edited my anwer and added working code of winforms.